# Can Hadoop have different data directories per machine?

Tags: hadoop

I'm working on setting up HDFS.
BTW, I'm only allowed to use specific directories.
Since, there are restricts of making directories, I'm stuck.

My question: is this possible to have different directories per machine?

```
e.g.
Machine 1 uses /hadoop/machine1/hdfs_root
Machine 2 uses /hadoop/machine2/hdfs_root
```

OR

is this possible to have system environment variables in config files?

```
e.g.
<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>/hadoop/$HOSTNAME/hdfs_root</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Note that it's a pain in the .... to maintain different configuration files as the number of nodes grow in the cluster. I don't think using $HOSTNAME in the hadoop configuration files is allowed.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to solve these kinds of problems with symlinks.  The same path (say, /home/myself/hdfsStorage) can be pointed to different places on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean where are the hdfs files stored, the yes.

the parameter `dfs.data.dir` in the hdfs config file controls the location of the hdfs data in each node.
there's a copy of the file on each node, and they may use different values in each node.

note that you need to format the hdfs filesystem before using it using the command `hadoop namenode -format`